# Read only unified directory

Tags: filesystems, samba

My end goal is that I want a samba share that displays all of the folders across several disks as one unified, read-only folder. This is for a NAS/media server setup.

Is there a way to create a unified folder that contains all of the subfolders of each of these drives in this way?

Comment: I guess you could do that with symlinks, but what's supposed to happen if you have a subdir `/foo` on more than one disk?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a union file system like `aufs` on Linux:

```
set /disk1 /disk2 /disk3
mount -t aufs -o br"$(printf ':%s=ro' "$@")" aufs /union/disk
```

(if files are common between the disks, the one from `disk1` takes precedence)

Comment: out of interest, would this work for a non-readonly folder?

Comment: @MurrayWaters, yes, the typical usage of `aufs` is to make a read-only directory writable by layering a writable one on top of it (think of instance of a live CD which you can modify by writing the new files on a RAM FS). See the `aufs` man page for all the possibilities.