# Process overwrite access restriction

Tags: linux, permissions, filesystems, process-management

I want to run a program so that it can only **create new** files and not **overwrite** existing ones.

Does something like this exist?

```
$ fsaccess --can read,write --not overwrite --command bash -c 'echo "stuff" > filetim; echo "Woohoo I did it"'
```

Now if filetim doesn't exist, then the command should run just fine, but if filetim did exist then fsaccess would exit with a message like

```
Killed child! Command tried to overwrite a file. It does not have permission to do that!
```

Comment: Well in your example command you use `bash`, and bash has a `set -C` option which enables this behavior. But it will only apply to that specific bash. Any program launched by bash will not inherit it. The only option that springs to mind that work work for everything is to use `LD_PRELOAD` and override `open()` so that it adds `O_EXCL` when a file is opened for writing. But this is very dangerous as programs will not expect the behavior.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want a process to be able to create new files but not overwrite pre-existing files, run it as a dedicated user and don't give this user write access anywhere except in some initially-empty directories. That way the program will not have the permission to overwrite any pre-existing file.

If you want to run a program and let it pretend it's overwriting files when it isn't, give it write access only to dedicated directories as above, but in addition you can use a [union filesystem](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/78407/read-only-unified-directory/78413#78413) such as [aufs](http://aufs.sourceforge.net/aufs.html), [funionfs](http://funionfs.apiou.org/), [unionfs-fuse](http://podgorny.cz/moin/UnionFsFuse), …, to make another hierarchy appear to the program as well.

If you want to retain all the prior versions of the files overwritten by a process, restrict that process to a [copyfs](http://boklm.eu/copyfs/) filesystem, which retains all past versions of all files.

If you really need to allow the process to create new files but not to overwrite files, even its own, I don't think you'll find anything preexisting. You could write your own [FUSE](http://fuse.sourceforge.net/) filesystem.

Comment: For my current situation, copyfs is what I was looking for.

Comment: Copyfs is a cow (copy on write) filesystem. So is btrfs. Would btrfs work as well? Or is cowing not the only thing copyfs is doing to preserve previous versions of files?

Comment: @DanielTA Copy-on-write is an implementation technique. The relevant aspect of copyfs is that it doesn't delete older versions. Snapshots of btrfs, zfs or LVM also use copy-on-write techniques, but they're less suited for this use case as you need to explicitly create the snapshots, they don't automatically retain all versions of all files.